# C# changing the value of a field of a class for all other classes

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, properties

I have a class (class A) which has a method named methodA.

```
class A
{
    public Dictionary<string, double> methodA(double param1, double param2)
    {
      //do calculations
      return result;
    }

}
```

I have 9 other classes (Class B, C, ....). They all have a field named myField. The value of myField is calculated using methodA of Class A. They look like this:

```
class B
{
    private Dictionary<string, double> myField;
    private readonly A a = new A();
    public B()
    {
        myField = a.methodA(param1, param2)
    }
    // methods using myField    
}
```

param1 and param2 are values that never change and are stored elsewhere. So the value of myField is the same for all classes and over the complete runtime of the application. Now there is a design change. methodA is updated and checks if a certain condition is true and calculates the value of myField based on the condition and parameters param3, param4 which are changing during the runtime.

```
public Dictionary<string, double> methodA(double param1, double param2, double param3, double param4)
{
    if(condition)
    {
        result = .....
    } else {
        result = .....
    }      
    return result;
}
```

the condition is initially false and changes only once during the runtime. After that the value of myField should stay the same till the end of runtime.

How should I implement this in my class definitions, so that the value of myField is updated once after the condition is true and remains constant till the end of runtime?

Comment: You have to execute methodA again.

Comment: You could implement an AService thats holds reulst of A.methodA. myField in class B gets its value from AService.methodAResult.

Comment: You added depdendency-injection as a tag yet you don't use it in your examples. Implement it and make Class A a service that has a lifecycle like a singleton, then you inject it in your other classes and voila, you'll have the same instance everywhere with the same values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added dependency-injection as a tag yet you don't use it in your examples. Implement it and make Class A an injectable service (using an interface) that has a lifecycle like a singleton, then you inject it in your other classes and voila, you'll have the same instance everywhere with the same values. Here is how I usually do it:

```
Container.RegisterType<IAPICacheManager, APICacheManager>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Then magically it gets passed to your constructors:

```
public BinanceService(IAPICacheManager apiCache, string instanceName, List<object> tracking, IDataService dataService, IMapper mappingEngine) : base(instanceName, tracking)
    {
        _mappingEngine = mappingEngine;
        _dataService = dataService;

        if (apiCache != null)
        {
            _apiCache = apiCache;

            _cacheEnabled = true;
.....
```

Here is an example to get you started:
[Unity](https://www.accusoft.com/blog/dependency-injection-going-start-finish-unity-c/)

Answer (score 0):

If the value of myField has to be the same across all of your classes, I would consider making it a public static field

Comment: Totally not wrong, but keep in mind: everyone loves statics, but unit-testing does not!

Comment: That's something I actually hadn't thought about as haven't done a great amount of unit testing so far, thanks!